# how to separate svg defs from the tags?

Tags: html, svg

In my codepen example I have two svgs.

I want to move all the **defs** into one svg tag like so:

```
<svg>
 <defs>
  <pattern id="a" ......... />
  <pattern id="b" ......... />
 </defs>
</svg>
```

and all my path into separate svg tags like so:

```
<svg>
 <path fill="url(#a)" d="M................................. />
</svg>
<br>
<svg>
 <path fill="url(#b)" d="M................................. />
</svg>
```

The problem is when I do the image is not fill all the path..

So what I'm missing here?

[my codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQwrGa)